# How to install debcargo in Ubuntu? It is in the Debian repositories, but not in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, packaging, debian, rust

`debcargo` is a Debian package for packaging rust apps in .deb format. It is [available](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=debcargo) in Debian Buster and above, but I [could not find](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=debcargo) the package in Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10.

Why is the package not available in Ubuntu? Is it available under some other name?

Comment: Do you mean `dh-cargo` ?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=dh-cargo&searchon=names ; https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=debcargo&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all  *I'm out of my league here, so don't know if they are the same, or just similar/related*

Comment: debcargo was added to Ubuntu in 20.04. See [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository). However, it's in -proposed, so may not be ready for wide use.

Comment: @user535733, really https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=debcargo ? There is no /usr/bin/debcargo in https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/all/dh-cargo/filelist .

Comment: It's in -proposed. It shows up in rmadison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is available for Debian, then you can install it manually on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which is based on *bullseye*.

Use commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dh-cargo/dh-cargo_24_all.deb
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/rust-debcargo/debcargo_2.4.4-1_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libg/libgit2/libgit2-1.1_1.1.0+dfsg.1-4_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libgit2-1.1_1.1.0+dfsg.1-4_amd64.deb ./dh-cargo_24_all.deb ./debcargo_2.4.4-1_amd64.deb
```

and then start using `debcargo`.

---

If you prefer to use Ubuntu repositories - use package from *-proposed* pocket:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rust-debcargo/debcargo_2.4.2-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./debcargo_2.4.2-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: An alternative way is to enable proposed, as mentioned in the comments.